# Active Directory PSO fine grained passwords msDS-MaximumPasswordAge

Tags: vbscript

Looking how to create a vbscript to pull the maximum number of days a PSO policy has set. It comes back as a value of ... and I do not know how to get the real value that was set.

This is what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Const ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE = &H40
Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &H10000

Dim strFilePath, objFSO, objFile, adoConnection, adoCommand, objCDOConf
Dim objRootDSE, strDNSDomain, strFilter, strQuery, adoRecordset, objMaxPwdAge
Dim strDN, objShell, lngBiasKey, lngBias, blnPwdExpire, strDept, strAdd
Dim objDate, dtmPwdLastSet, lngFlag, k, address, objAdd, objMessage

' Check for required arguments.
If (Wscript.Arguments.Count < 1) Then
    Wscript.Echo "Arguments <FileName> required. For example:" & vbCrLf _
        & "cscript PwdLastChanged.vbs c:\MyFolder\UserList.txt"
    Wscript.Quit(0)
End If

strFilePath = Wscript.Arguments(0)
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Open the file for write access.
On Error Resume Next
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFilePath, 2, True, 0)
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Wscript.Echo "File " & strFilePath & " cannot be opened"
    Wscript.Quit(1)
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
lngBiasKey = objShell.RegRead("HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\" _
    & "TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias")
If (UCase(TypeName(lngBiasKey)) = "LONG") Then
    lngBias = lngBiasKey
ElseIf (UCase(TypeName(lngBiasKey)) = "VARIANT()") Then
    lngBias = 0
    For k = 0 To UBound(lngBiasKey)
        lngBias = lngBias + (lngBiasKey(k) * 256^k)
    Next
End If

' Use ADO to search the domain for all users.
Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOOBject"
adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection

' Determine the DNS domain from the RootDSE object.
Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("DefaultNamingContext")

' Filter to retrieve all user objects.
strFilter = "(&(objectClass=msDS-PasswordSettings))"

' Filter to retrieve all computer objects.    
strQuery = "<LDAP://CN=PSO-Information Systems,CN=Password Settings Container,CN=System,DC=yrmc,DC=org>;" _
    & ";cn,msDS-LockoutDuration,msDS-MaximumPasswordAge,msDS-

PasswordSettingsPrecedence;subtree"

    adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
    adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100
    adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
    adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False

Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute
Do Until adoRecordset.EOF
    objFile.WriteLine adoRecordset.Fields("cn").Value
    adoRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
adoRecordset.Close
```

I can get a value for cn and even `msDS-PasswordSettingsPrecedence` but not for `msDS-MaximumPasswordAge`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is at best a partial answer but I did some searching and I believe you will need one or more of the following:

1. [DSGet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770848%28v=ws.10%29)/DSQuery
2. [LDIFDE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754461%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to manage PSO's.
3. Quest's "[Free PowerShell Commands for Active Directory](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx)"

Using Quest's free tools, you might find this [link](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/permissions/use-powershell-to-manage-fine-grained-password-policies-in-windows-server-2008) handy

Answer (score 0):

Put square brackets around our Active Directory attribute name:

See the blog post ["How can I retrieve the value of an active directory attribute that has a hyphen in its name"](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/06/21/how-can-i-retrieve-the-value-of-an-active-directory-attribute-that-has-a-hyphen-in-its-name.aspx) for more.

Answer (score 0):

you have to find UsersPSO location in your AD like that

```
domainLookupString = ""CN=UsersPSO,CN=Password Settings Container,CN=System,DC=COMPAY,DC=ORG";
```

then run the ldap query

```
ldapFilterString = "(&(objectClass=msDS-PasswordSettings))";
```

at the end, get the ldap attribute with the Maximum Password Age of the current PSO policy

```
"msDS-MaximumPasswordAge"
```